# $P$ is a change of basis matrix from basis $B$ to basis $C$. Given $P$ and $C$ find $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, change-of-basis

> $$
> P=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&3&2\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}
> $$ is a change of basis matrix from  basis $B$ to basis $C$.
>   $$
> C=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   Find $B$.

The way I understand this is that $C=PBP^{-1}$, then $B=P^{-1}CP$. So I need to find $P^{-1}$ which is:
$$
P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&2\\0&1&-2\\0&-1&3\end{pmatrix}
$$
However when I compute $B=P^{-1}CP$ my solution the result is wrong when compared with the correct solution.

The correct solution also finds the same matrix $P^{-1}$ but after that it is as follows:

let $B=(b_1,b_2,b_3), C=(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ then:
$$
b_1=c_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\\
b_2=-c_1+c_2-v_3=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}\\
b_3=2c_1-2c_2+3c_3=\begin{pmatrix}3\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}
$$
What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: Could I suggest writing the last three lines as vectors to avoid confusion? And also 'let $B=(\vec b_1 \,|\, \vec b_2,|\, \vec b_3)$...' is the usual convention

Comment: @Shuri2060 what do you mean, writing them in matrix notation?

Comment: @Shuri2060 right, I just don't understand what you meant by "writing them as vectors". Did you mean  $b_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: This area isn't one of my strengths so I don't see it yet, but notice that the coefficients of $c_i$ in the solution correspond to the respective columns of $P^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes I did notice that. But I want to understand what is wrong with my solution. And after I corrected $P^{-1}_{1,3}$ it still doesn't check out

Comment: Ah right I see - $B=CP^{-1}$

Comment: Can't believe I didn't spot it before, but since matrix $P$ changes from basis $B$ to $C$, that would be true. So $C=BP$ is what you should've started with

Comment: Nice! I didn't realize that $BP=C\Rightarrow B=CP^{-1}$. You should post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it shortly, $C=BP$ because of how the change of basis matrix is [defined](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofCoordinatesMatrix.html) as well as how matrices $B$ and $C$ represent their respective bases.

I'll include the long version below, however.

---

For bases $B=\{\vec b_1,...,\vec b_n\}$ and $C=\{\vec c_1,...,\vec c_n\}$, the change of basis matrix, $P$, is defined such that

$$(\forall j)\,\,\vec c_j=\sum_{i=1}^nP_{ij}\vec b_i$$

Let $[\vec v]_A$ represent the components of some vector $\vec v$ in some basis $A=\{\vec a_1,...,\vec a_n\}$, and ${([\vec v]_A)}_i$ represent the $i$th component. Then

$$\vec v=\sum_{i=1}^n{([\vec v]_A)}_i\vec a_i$$

$\implies$

$$(\forall j)\,\,\sum_{k=1}^n{([\vec c_j]_E)}_k\vec e_k=\sum_{i=1}^nP_{ij}\sum_{k=1}^n{([\vec b_i]_E)}_k\vec e_k$$

Note that (what I assume to be) your book lets matrices $B=([\vec b_1]_E\,|\,...\,|\,[\vec b_n]_E)$ and $C=([\vec c_1]_E|...|[\vec c_n]_E)$ (where '$|$' concatenates vectors and $E=\{\vec e_1,...,\vec e_n\}$ is the standard basis).

Using that, we get

$$(\forall j)\,\,\sum_{k=1}^nC_{kj}\vec e_k=\sum_{i=1}^nP_{ij}\sum_{k=1}^nB_{ki}\vec e_k$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^nB_{ki}P_{ij}\right)\vec e_k$$

$\implies$ (using ${(AB)}_{ij}=\sum_kA_{ik}B_{kj}$ from matrix multiplication)

$$(\forall j)\,\,\sum_{k=1}^nC_{kj}\vec e_k=\sum_{k=1}^n{(BP)}_{kj}\vec e_k$$

As $E$ is a basis, and so the vectors $\vec e_1,...,\vec e_n$ are linearly independent, we can conclude

$$(\forall j,k)\,\,C_{kj}={(BP)}_{kj}$$

$\implies$

$$C=BP$$